# Wrong/no formatting Word files inserted in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, windows-10, microsoft-power-map-excel

I'm using ESRI ArcView 9.3.1, and in a project in ArcMap I need to insert a Word file formatted (a table + text, bolded, centered, colored etc.). In Layout View the inserted object shows as in Microsoft Word. But when I'm exporting the map (such as Export to ...jpg, png or pdf) the result with the Word file included is bulk with no formatting. 
This error (not retaining the word file formatted) appeared suddenly after no change to the program (ESRI ArcView 9.3.1.) and to the computer (Microsoft Windows 10 64 bits).

I have reinstalled Esri ArcView and the problem isn't solved.

Here is a sample with the problem:  [image: non formatted table]

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: ArcGIS 9.3.x has been in Retired support status for a long time. It was never certified with Windows 10 (ArcGIS 10.3.1 was the first). It's likely that an OS patch destabilized your old software.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to export your word doc to an image and add that to your map layout.  This should work fine in 9.3.

To do this, you can use a few methods.  One is to use a screen capture tool to take a screenshot of the word doc (lower quality, but fast).

Another method is to export the doc to pdf, open the pdf, export the pdf to an image.